# Caching a specific URL path in Varnish fails

Tags: varnish

I've set up some VCL to only cache the /js/ folder.

```
sub vcl_backend_response {
   if (bereq.url ~ "^/js/.$") {
       unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
       set beresp.http.cache-control = "max-age = 2592000";
       set beresp.ttl = 1y;
   }else {
       set beresp.http.cache-control = "max-age = 0";
       set beresp.ttl = 0s;
   }
}
```

When I check the cache status of items in the js folder after reloading a few times, nothing has been cached and the cache control header shows 0.

```
# curl -I localhost:6081/js/themes.js
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/javascript
Etag: W/"1655132873"
Last-Modified: Mon, 13 Jun 2022 15:07:53 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Length: 656
Date: Thu, 11 Aug 2022 19:13:50 GMT
cache-control: max-age = 0
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Varnish: 5
Age: 0
Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/6.5)
Connection: keep-alive
```

Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `vcl_backend_response` subroutine is called prior to storing an object in the cache. The VCL logic you provided will at least ensure that the Javascript ends up in the cache.

However, I'm not too sure that your `^/js/.$"` regular expression will match the right URLs. Maybe `^/js/.*$` would be a better match.

### Built-in VCL for vcl_backend_response

There may also be other factors that prevent the object from being stored in te cache. If you take a look at the following tutorial about Varnish's built-in VCL, you'll see what logic is applied: https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/varnish-builtin-vcl/#11-vcl_backend_response

If the response contains a `Cache-Control: no-cache` or a `Cache-Control: no-store` or a `Cache-Control: private` header, Varnish will still not store the object in the cache.

To prevent this from happening, you can actually call `return(deliver)`. This wil bypass any other built-in VCL logic.

Here's what your VCL code would look like:

```
sub vcl_backend_response {
   if (bereq.url ~ "^/js/.*$") {
       unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
       set beresp.http.cache-control = "max-age = 2592000";
       set beresp.ttl = 1y;
       return(deliver);
   }else {
       set beresp.http.cache-control = "max-age = 0";
       set beresp.ttl = 120s;
       set beresp.uncacheable = true;
       return(deliver);
   }
}
```

However, built-in VCL logic mostly makes sense, so I'd be very cautious when bypassing it.

> You probably noticed that I removed `set beresp.ttl=0` from the VCL example and replaced it with `set beresp.uncacheable=true`. That's because you should never set the TTL to zero. For reasons that are not relevant to this question, they will make Varnish perform really poorly and will cause increased backend fetches to your backend.

### Built-in VCL for vcl_recv

While we discussed how to force objects to be stored in the cache through `vcl_backend_response` logic, that doesn't mean the object will be served from the cache. That's where the built-in VCL for `vcl_recv` comes into play.

See https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/varnish-builtin-vcl/#1-vcl_recv for a tutorial about the `vcl_recv` built-in VCL.

If a request contains a `Cookie` or an `Authorization` header, Varnish will not serve the object from cache, despite it being static content.

To bypass this behavior, you could also add the following code:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.url ~ "^/js/.*$") {
        unset req.http.Cookie;
        unset req.http.Authorization;
        return(hash);
    }
}
```

This will ensure all content from the `/js/` folder will be served from the cache.

### VCL template for caching static data

If it's your goal to cache static data regardless of the folder it is stored in, you can use the following VCL template:

```
sub vcl_recv {
    if (req.url ~ "^[^?]*\.(7z|avi|bmp|bz2|css|csv|doc|docx|eot|flac|flv|gif|gz|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|less|mka|mkv|mov|mp3|mp4|mpeg|mpg|odt|ogg|ogm|opus|otf|pdf|png|ppt|pptx|rar|rtf|svg|svgz|swf|tar|tbz|tgz|ttf|txt|txz|wav|webm|webp|woff|woff2|xls|xlsx|xml|xz|zip)(\?.*)?$") {
        unset req.http.Cookie;
        unset req.http.Authorization
        return(hash);
    }
}

sub vcl_backend_response {
    if (bereq.url ~ "^[^?]*\.(7z|avi|bmp|bz2|css|csv|doc|docx|eot|flac|flv|gif|gz|ico|jpeg|jpg|js|less|mka|mkv|mov|mp3|mp4|mpeg|mpg|odt|ogg|ogm|opus|otf|pdf|png|ppt|pptx|rar|rtf|svg|svgz|swf|tar|tbz|tgz|ttf|txt|txz|wav|webm|webp|woff|woff2|xls|xlsx|xml|xz|zip)(\?.*)?$") {
        unset beresp.http.Set-Cookie;
        set beresp.ttl = 1d;
    }
}
```

It comes from the following tutorial: https://www.varnish-software.com/developers/tutorials/example-vcl-template/#13-caching-static-content.

You can still adjust it by increasing the TTL or by prefixing the specific folder in the regex.